# Texture is blurry in Blender when quick editing with GIMP

Tags: texture-painting

I've been following this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UVClJ61GrbQ. Essentially I'm quick editing with GIMP.

However, textures always come through kinda squiggly/blurry. I've tried 4096x4096 textures as well as 4096x4096 screen grab, and I'm about as zoomed in as the screenshots. Yet everything is still blurry. Note that I am removing the layer with the Glock in it before applying.

The generated PNG is not blurry if I open it as normal in a photos program.

After i click "Apply" in Blender:
[image: After i click "Apply" in Blender]

Original shape in GIMP:
[image: Original shape in GIMP]

Some things I tried:

- I changed the Material's Interpolation to Closest
- Un-ticked "Anti-aliasing" under Advanced in Paint mode within the
  Image Editor for my texture
- Depth of Field is disabled.
- Increased texture resolution

Comment: I think this is because your mesh has uneven faces/ngons so triangles.

Comment: @lemon Yes I think you're right https://imgur.com/a/R4Y8VrK. But how would I fix it? This is a model taken from the game CSGO and is used by thousands

Comment: it depend a bit on what the texture should do. But best way may be to clean the mesh, at least for the parts you're interested in here (black parts).

Comment: @lemon The idea is to create CSGO skins like this one https://imgur.com/a/Znas9Js which are then flattened into a .vtf. Not sure if I can clean the mesh without interrupting the normal process of making skins

Comment: Have you tried to render it as it is in CS?

Comment: As I wrote [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/292118/how-can-i-fix-this-uv#comment502988_292118) - duplicate, subdivide, bake to the original.

Comment: @MarkusvonBroady Thanks -- any chance you'd be able to lay that out a bit more explicitly in an answer please? I'm quite new to Blender

Comment: I added the answer to the post I linked above.