# How do I distort a 3d animation on a horizontal table for an observer who is sitting at the table?

Tags: uv

Scenario:
A person is sitting at a dining table, looking down at it, as would someone looking at his plate, while a projector fixed on the ceiling is projecting a 3d animated video on the table.
The 3d animation displays miniature figures cooking food from a top down perspective, the content of this 3d animation starts from the edge of the table at the persons chest (depending on the height of the table) and ends at the middle of the table.

Problem:
for that projection to appear 3d (illusion) to the perspective of observer (person), I need to make a distorted view then project in on the table.

How would I achieve that using blender?

Answer (score 1):

If the projector's normal is the reverse of the table's surface normal (projector "looks" at the table "head on"), then it's as simple as putting a plane (or using the part of the table's surface) and assign a material with an image sequence/video to it:

[image]

If the projector is at some angle: the easiest solution would be to use a camera to represent the projector, press <kbd>Numpad 0</kbd>, and resize the plane to fill the camera view (or UV unwrap to align with camera view), then subdivide the plane (I explain why [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/292118/how-can-i-fix-this-uv/292244#comment502987_292118)) and cut the excess:

[image]

Giving the result:

[image]

For anything more complex: either really simulate it with a texture on the light, or use geometry nodes to raycast toward a point behind the plane and assign the UV of the plane in the place the ray has hit…

Comment: The projector's normal is the reverse of the table's normal. The problem here is the perspective of the observer. How will I trick the eyes of the observer to see the 3d animation as 3d hologram illusion, as if the animation is popping out. how will i recreate that optical illusion ? This is an example of what im trying to do : https://youtu.be/4Ma4rxgNTG8?feature=shared&t=187